# App in docker container runs again and exits with message - fileds may not be blank

Tags: django, shell, docker, dockerfile, entry-point

I have a django app which runs fine on local. But when I build the docker image and run the app from within the container, it runs fine and return status 200, but after some time it again returns status 400 with message, input fields are blank.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
No changes detected
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 25, 2020 - 12:09:24
Django version 1.11.23, using settings 'TestSop.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8016/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[25/Mar/2020 12:09:35] "GET /TestSopApiView/ HTTP/1.1" 405 12315
[25/Mar/2020 12:09:41] "GET /TestSopApiView/ HTTP/1.1" 405 12315

[25/Mar/2020 12:10:03] "POST /TestSopApiView/ HTTP/1.1" 200 205
[25/Mar/2020 12:11:23] "POST /TestSopApiView/ HTTP/1.1" 400 189
{"field1":["This field may not be blank."],"field2":["This field may not be blank."],"field3":["This field may not be blank."],"field4":["This field may not be blank."]}
```

This is my Dockerfile-

```
FROM python:3.7

#Create Directory in Container
ADD . /TestSop

WORKDIR /TestSop

COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8016

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y jq

RUN chmod +x /TestSop/entrypoint.sh
RUN touch /TestSop/TestSop.log
RUN chmod 777 /TestSop/TestSop.log

ENTRYPOINT ["/TestSop/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh -

```
#!/bin/sh
python /TestSop/manage.py makemigrations &
python /TestSop/manage.py migrate &
python /TestSop/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8016 &

sleep 2m

curl_output=$(curl -X POST -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"field1": "'"$field1"'","field2":"'"$field2"'","field3":"'"$field3"'","field4":"'"$field4"'"}' http://127.0.0.1:8016/TestSopApiView/)

echo $curl_output


result=$(echo $curl_output | jq ".result")


if [ "${result}" = "\"fail\"" ] 
then
  exit 255
else
  exit 0
fi

exec "$@"
```

Can you tell me why there is this second run happening with 400 status inside the container? It does not seem to cause any error though. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say, you get 400, are you calling the app from within the container?

Comment: Yes, locally i get 200. But within the container 200 and then 400 after some time.